# Removing sharing permissions from subfolder to group, without removing them from parent folder

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-drive-sharing, permissions

In Google Workspace, I have a folder tree shared with several Google Groups. As a rule, subfolders inherit the same permissions of the folders tree's root folder.

If folder `parent` is shared with groups `admin` and `staff`, say, how can I remove sharing permissions to `staff` on subfolder `child`, without removing these permissions on `parent` as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this about Google Workspace `Shared Drives`?  Are you using the term `Google Groups` in the way that Google defines it, or are you referring to organizational groups within your Workspace Domain?  Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Yes, by Google Groups I am referring to "mailing lists", not to organizational groups. The list address is in the workspace domain, although occasionally a few list's members may not have an address within that domain. Concerning the type of drive, yes, I think it is a Shared Drive within the Google Workspace.